# GOMAXPROCS for Go service in Kubernetes

Tags: go, kubernetes, concurrency

I'm trying to stress test our Go service in kubernetes.
The service is just an http server that accepts requests, send requests to another service, perform some string manipulations and return back response to the original request.

We started with

```
cpu.requests = 1
cpu.limit = 2
Note: host VM has 6 CPUs
```

With the following test scenario:

```
Repeat for 20 times:
1. Send 40 parallel requests
2. Sleep for 200ms
```

What we observed is Gomaxprocs by default is set to 6 (following host specs)
and we get network i/o timeout after some iterations of test.
In addition, cpu consumption falls to 0 after some time (any idea what might happen here? Go runtime scheduler get stuck?)

Issue is resolved by setting Gomaxprocs explicitly to 1.

Some basic Googling led me to article like https://github.com/uber-go/automaxprocs/issues/12
But not many other articles/documentations that warn us about this GOMAXPROCS behavior on kubernetes.

Help appreciated:

1. Any other articles that elaborate how misconfigured GOMAXPROCS affect Go service in kubernetes?
2. What to do if cpu.requests is set to 500mCPU? is GOMAXPROCS=1 still adequate? or it simply means cpu.requests must be at least 1?

Comment: It's inadvisable to set GOMAXPROCS > number of CPUs available (but I don't think that is the problem).  I think you are setting your container to use 2 cpus so set GOMAXPROCS to 2 (or maybe 1 depending on whether your container is running anything else). I presume that CPU "falls to zero" means everything stops.  To me this sounds like a deadlock that is triggered under load (but not triggered when you set GOMAXPROCS to 1 as often happens). Try running your code with race detection turned on.

Comment: I tried with -race, nothing interesting caught.. and some update: even with GOMAXPROCS=1, apparently I'm still hitting network timeout sometimes (and cpu falls to 0). number of goroutines eventually fall too, so I doubt it's some kind of deadlock at application level. I do not have such issue when running the application outside k8s environment.

Comment: Update: we found out that we had some issues with our nginx that caused network instability. Issue has nothing to do with Gomaxprocs. But as pointed out by @AndrewW.Phillips, it's still a good idea not to use GOMAXPROCS > CPUs available. https://github.com/uber-go/automaxprocs seems to be a good tool for this.